# Flex vertical scroll bar is not appear when datagrid is disabled

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I'm new to action script. i have created datagrid in a form.

i have disabled the datagrid with tons of records when vertical scroll bar is not working.

So i can view only limited rows in datagrid and rest of rows i can't view.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? Some code would also help.

Comment: What he said. Also, if the grid is truly disabled, I think it makes sense that there are no scroll bars (if they were present they would be disabled, so why waste cycles on showing them). Please clarify your question, and showing whatever code you have is always helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you're mixing up `enabled` and `editable`? The former will completely disable the component, including the scrollbars as @SunilD. pointed out. The latter will prevent the user from being able to edit the cells.

Comment: i have loaded 300 records in datagrid while loading form but i have disabled for view only and it should not be editable. so scroll bar of the grid is disabled. so that i can view only 20 - 30 rows only. rest of the records i am unable to view.